# post table data to MVC action using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have a web page with some input field and the datatable to handle some client-side actions. I am using ASP MVC to control the server side process and i am quite stuck at how I can submit the form with some fields in the datatable.

Simply, my page is like below.

```
<form id="formID" action="test" class="form-horizontal">
    <select class="form-control valid" data-val="true" id="SelectedCustomerID" name="SelectedCustomerID">
        <option value="">choose customer ... </option>
        <option value="1">test</option>
    </select>

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <input type="number" name="row-1-input1" id="row-1-input1" class="input-xs" value="2">
                <input type="number" name="row-1-input2" id="row-1-input2" class="input-xs" value="test">
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <input type="number" name="row-2-input1" id="row-2-input1" class="input-xs" value="3">
                <input type="number" name="row-2-input2" id="row-2-input2" class="input-xs" value="test2">
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="submit" class="btn yellow-gold add">add</button>
</from>
```

I am struggling with how I can submit this form and pass all the input fields to handle the input fields in the table.

How can I use ajax to submit the form and pass all these input fields and how this can be mapped with the MVC model ?

```
$('#formID').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/pathTo/process_form',
            data: <---- what needs to go here ... ?
        });
    });
```

Comment: What model? Show the relevant code! Do you really have a model with properties `row-1-input1` and `row-1-input2` etc?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#formID').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataToPost = $(this).serialize()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/pathTo/process_form',
            data: JSON.stringify({ data: dataToPost }),
        });
    });
```

Comment: okay got to that stage but how do I map that dataToPost to mvc model ? because if I just take it as string argument it fails ..

Comment: I think It will bind automatically.

Comment: what do you mean by it will bind automatically .. ?

Comment: public ActionResult ActionName(ModelName name){}

Comment: You need the `name` attributes on your `<input>`s to match the property names on your model, and the MVC framework will do the rest.

Comment: Okay so how that ModelName class needs to be defined in order to accept all input fields in the form ?

Comment: @krillgar so i have list of rows in the datatable with different name.. how can this be matched on the model ?

Comment: Yes and and you must use html Helpers in MVC

Comment: I am not using html helpers in MVC because i am using jquery datatable plugin with server side ajax to populate the table... i don't see there is much difference as long the name fields can be mapped. @GhanshyamSingh

Comment: @superted Hopefully with a table, each row would be a logical parallel of some sort of Model or Entity object. Or, you could create a Model that matches the inputs in each row and do whatever magic you need to on the server. It's impossible to say with what you've shown us because you don't have descriptive names for anything.